# Are pub/sub messageIds the same for duplicates?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

This is a simple question that isn't [answered in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) - if a pubsub message is redelivered, is the messageId the same as the original attempt or does it change with each subsequent delivery attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of delivery. Publish to a topic and delivery to a subscriber.

The publish can result in duplicate messages with unique message IDs.

Once a message is successfully published to a topic, delivery retries will have the same message ID.

Also, note that Pub/Sub guarantees at least once delivery for every subscription. This means that a message may be delivered more than once by the same subscription. These duplicate messages will have the same message ID.

Reference: [Handling duplicate data in streaming pipelines using Dataflow and Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow)

Comment: If a message is successfully published to a topic only once (no source duplicates) and is pushed to a subscriber, will any duplicate deliveries due to an acknowledgment delay by the subscriber have the same or different messageIds?

Comment: @randomdatascientist - They will have the same message ID.